# The name 'Scripts' does not exists in the current context in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my mvc application, In the _Layout.cshtml has code below...

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
```

But the problem is it says `The name 'Scripts' does not exists in the current context`.

I have already added the assembly to the reference and to the Bundle config as `using System.Web.Optimization;`

This happens for **@styles** also..
What should I do?

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Make sure your `~/Views/Web.Config` adds the `System.Web.Optimization` namespace:

```c#
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: your solution worked, error has gone but still not able to get intelligence in .cshtml pages, any idea why?

Comment: You don't have Intellisense at all? Or just for `Styles` and `Scripts`?

Comment: No Intellisense at all in views (.cshtml).

Comment: This has nothing to do with `System.Web.Optimization`. But see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22832435/mvc-razor-view-intellisense-broken-in-vs-2013

Comment: Nope, earlier it was throwing error `The name 'Scripts' does not exists in the current context` which has gone after adding `System.Web.Optimization` in view's web.config, but yeah intellisense is still same, okay thanks let me check that question.

Comment: For intelligence problem after adding the web.optimization in config file. 
Close all the open tab in visual studio.
Clean the project and build the project.
Open the .cshtml file and check whether intelligence work or not if not then again rebuild it. Now it should work.

Comment: @Dipitak EXCELLENT suggestion.  Closed my Layout.cshtml page, did a rebuild on my solution, re-opened the page.  It took it about 15 seconds or so still, after opening the page up, to get it, but it did finally clear those red squigglies & recognize `Scripts` and `Styles`.  Wow...

Comment: Note:  I also needed to include the `@using System.Web.Optimization` statement in the _Layout.cshtml file.  I have a project where this is not necessary and it works fine, but for some reason in this project it needed it.

Comment: This worked for me, but only once I installed Microsoft.Aspnet.Web.Optimization from NuGet - possibly because I upgraded my project from 4.6.0 to 4.6.2, but worth checking for anyone else having issues

Comment: it didn't work.

Answer (score 40):

The following in .chtml solves the problem

```
@using System.Web.Optimization
@Scripts.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
```

Comment: It worked!! 

but why it doesn't work when adding namespace in **Views/web.config**

Comment: @AsadShakeel Had the same issue & got mine working the same way. I found if you then removed `@using System.Web.Optimization` again & closed the _Layouts.cshtml file & rebuilt the solution, then re-opened the file, the intellisense was broken again. Putting the line back, without a rebuild, immediately restored it. This was in a project that didn't originally have a BundleConfig class (& wasn't registered in Global.ascx.cs) and System.Web.Optimization wasn't originally in my web.config. Added all that manually. In projects that had the BundleConfig.cs from the beginning, never had this issue.

Comment: @hechchatt : here you are the reposne

Answer (score 18):

Please Follow My Step will Clear this

First

- Install `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimisation`
- Check that the `App_Start` Folder contains a `BundleConfig.cs` File.
- Add `<namespaces>
          <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        </namespaces>`
  in `Views/web.config` File
- Add `BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);` in `Global.asax.cs`
- Rebuild and Run it

Answer (score 3):

There is still intellisense problem, you can add this code to Application_Start() method that inside global.asax file.

```
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

Comment: This could be a part of the problem, but more accurate to include ensuring the `System.Web.Optimization` namespace is registered (Referenced Assemblies, web.config, `using` statement...).

Answer (score 1):

In VisualStudio 2019,I was able to solve this error.
Microsoft.Web.Optimization is now included in the 'Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization' package.
Using NuGet Packing Manager download the  package.
In .cshtml file add "@using System.Web.Optimization;

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to fix this issue is by downloading (Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization) from Nuget Package Manager.

Steps:

1. Right-click on the Solution.
2. Choose "Manage Nuget packages for solutions"
3. Search for (Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization) and download--> apply
   it on the project.
4. Close all the open pages in Visual Studio, and re-open them,

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to add the nuget package

Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization

to your project.