# Use async with @Html.Script

Tags: c#, razor, sitefinity

I would like to add the async property to the resulting script tag when I use the @Html.Script Razor syntax

```
@if (!SitefinityContext.IsBackend) { @Html.Script("/Path/to/javascript/file/products.min.js", "bottom") }
```

I know there is also this one:

```
@Html.Raw("<script src='/Path/to/javascript/file/products.min.js' async></script>")
```

But with this I can't specify the "bottom" parameter as above. Any idea?

Comment: Try this: `@if (!SitefinityContext.IsBackend) {@Html.Script(Url.Content(@Scripts.RenderFormat(@"<script src=""{0}"" async></script>", "/Path/to/javascript/file/products.min.js").ToString()), "bottom")}`

Comment: Hm. It puts a red line under @Scripts and tells me "The name Scripts does not exist in the current context".

Comment: Okay, this link can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23534516/the-name-scripts-does-not-exists-in-the-current-context-in-mvc

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either. I tried this now:
``` 
{@Html.Script(Url.Content(String.Format(@"<script src=""{0}"" async></script>", "/Link/to/Javascript/products.min.js").ToString()), "bottom")}```

But that results in this:

```
<script src="<script src=";/Link/To/JS/products.min.js" async></script>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Okay, can just try putting in the format without the `Url.Content`. Something like this: `{@Html.Script(String.Format("<script src=""{0}"" async></script>", "/Link/to/Javascript/products.min.js"), "bottom")}`

Comment: I guess this can't work because the Html.Script already generates a script tag and as long as I have another <script> tag in the string, it will always be double. The issue is that I need the Html.Script so I can specify the "bottom" as parameter so it places the script tag at the bottom of the page. But I can't add the async to it if it gets generated. Hm.

Comment: Okay. I understand why this is happening. Have you tried to create a new "placeholder area" in your master layout cshtml file right above the closing body tag using `@Html.SfPlaceHolder("Bottom")`. This will create a draggable area in Sitefinity page edit mode, so you could drag any widget you want into this area including Javascript widget (for any js code).

Comment: Yes, this was the idea I also had. I think this is the only way we can handle this. Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. No, I didn't find a solution to do it programmatically so I skipped this for now and decided to tackle it together with our .Net developer when he has time. For now creating the new placeholder area is the only way I could handle it and that's totally fine.