# razor 5.x view intellisence broken after nuget update when changing host factory version

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller, nuget, intellisense

I have updated the NuGet package "Microsoft ASP.NET MVC" and dependencies from version 5.0.0.0 to version 5.2.2.0

To have all references refer to the correct assambly I have updated Views/Web.config manually (like described in most solutions on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25941675/razor-syntax-gives-errors-in-view-before-compiling-no-intellisense) and most tutorials). this results in the following configuration:

```
<configSections>
 <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
   <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
   <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
 </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<system.web.webPages.razor>
 <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />

 <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
   <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
   <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
   <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
   <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
   <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
   <add namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions"/>
  </namespaces>
 </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Everything builds, however it breaks intellisence on all .cshtml razor pages:

```
The name 'model' does not exist in the current context
```

When I set the host factoryType version to 5.0.0.0 intellisence works again.
The strange thing is this in not a refered assembly.

I have tried these solutions:

- remove obj folder, bin folder and all packages from solution and rebuild
- fix `Copy Local = True` or `<Private>True</Private>` from [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26406804/after-windows-update-the-type-or-namespace-name-html-does-not-exist-in-the-na)

  ```
  <Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
    <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.2.2\lib\net45\System.Web.Mvc.dll</HintPath>
    <Private>True</Private>
  </Reference>
  ```
- tried to change version of `<section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, ..." ... />`

Do you know why this issue occurs, and how the intellisense can use the 5.0.0.0 version while that assembly is not even in the packages folder? (I checked)