# Visual Studio 2015 razor editor not working

Tags: visual-studio, razor, visual-studio-2015, ide

My razor file is not having proper highlighting and intellisense is not working.

**Razor file in vs2015 image:-**

 [image]

I tried solutions in [Visual Studio 2015 not syntax highlighting razor nor Intellisense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30311355/visual-studio-2015-not-syntax-highlighting-razor-nor-intellisense) , [Visual Studio 2015 Razor View MVC Types not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31594763/visual-studio-2015-razor-view-mvc-types-not-recognized) but it didn't help me.

I installed vs2015 (with update 3) two days before. So i didn't try reinstalling it.

Comment: Is this html inside a razor code -block? Can you post more code from the view?

Comment: It contains razor code also, html intellisense is also not working, all the file is opened as text file. I thing there is some issue with the built in editor for razor but i can't figure what is wrong.. :(

Comment: @Sardar_Usama thanks for your response. i found solution for the issue happened to my vs2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some search i found the solution. the issue was with the Microsoft web development tool it was not installed correctly( I still don't know why :) ) in my system when i install visual studio 2015. When i tried to modify the visual studio it didn't let me install web development tool (Update button was disabled). So i tried an alternative solution install asp.net core https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows because i know it comes with web development tool so i just tried installing and it fixed my issue.