# Getting MVC 3 razor view intellisense to work with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, visual-studio-2013

I am facing the same issue sited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19567235/limited-intelliesense-in-vs2013-on-mvc3-project). Basically, the MVC3 razor view (cshtml) intellisense does not work with VS 2013. The reason sited on that thread is that MVC3 is not supported in VS 2013. Now I have a third party library (dll) that I cannot upgrade to MVC4 or MVC5 without incurring additional cost. I am doubtful whether the MVC3 version of that library that I am currently using will correctly work with MVC4 if I upgrade my VS 2013 project to MVC4 for intellisense.

Coming back to my question, is there any way to get the VS 2013 razor view intellisense working for MVC3 . Other than intellisense, there is no issue and the project compiles and runs without any problems.

**EDIT**

As can be seen from the snapshot below, intellisense works for some statements like **@Html.Label(..)** but not for **@Html.DisplayFor(..)**, **Html.TextAreaFor(..)** and others.[image]

Answer (score 4):

Add these two lines inside each view:

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<dynamic>
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html
```

Instead of `dynamic` put your Model's type name.